# Calendar Control for Scheduling Recurring Tasks

Tags: c#, wpf, scheduled-tasks

Does anyone know where I can view some examples of source for implementing a `CalendarControl` similar to that in MS Outlook for scheduling Daily, weekly and Monthly recurring tasks?

I'm using WPF Forms, C# and VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to pay for it, I'd suggest: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Scheduler/index.xml

Otherwise, read this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOutlookCalendar.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOutlookCalendar2.aspx

http://rudigroblerwp.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/timeslotpanel/

http://rudigroblerwp.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/who%E2%80%99s-the-boss/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a control  here is a sample

http://www.tanvtech.com/Products/SchoolStudentScheduler.aspx